# Radio buttons instead of dropdown

Tags: forms

I have a problem, my client needs me to change a drop down menu to a radio button selection, 1 of them, needs to be endless options to be clicked, the other max of 4 out of 10.

This is what my form looks like:

```
 <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td width="35%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
          <td width="52%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
          <td width="13%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="subject">Area of Interest</label></td>
          <td><select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
            <option value="interactiveDinner">Interactive Dinner Series</option>
            <option value="winemakerDinner">Winemaker Dinners</option>
            <option value="Culinary Travel">Culinary Travel Adventures</option>
            <option value="education">Food & Beverage Education</option>
            <option value="host a Shikany Event">Host an event at your location</option>
            <option value="partnership">Partner with us</option>
            <option value="Hire Shikany">Hire Chef Michael Shikany for your event</option>
             <option value="Charity Inquiry">Charity / Philanthrophy / Non-profit Inquiry</option>
                     </select>          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="message">Please provide color to your inquiry</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />

height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      <?=$success?>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you using to generate the drop-down. Is it simple HTML and rendered via java or are you using php with db calls;)

Comment: thanks fabian, im using php w jqtransform.  i changed it to checkboxes instead of radio buttons...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use check boxes instead of radio buttons. That will allow the user to select as many of the options as they want. To limit the number of selections they can make to 4, you can use the code found at http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, you are right, im using checkboxes now... but im having issues centering the text properly with the checkboxes.... im using jqtransform to make the form look a bit better... any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your code with the check boxes and the jqtransform, as well as your css, so we can see what it might be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve what you describe with radio buttons, you will need to use checkboxes. This is simply so more than one option can be selected.

Also if you name each checkbox in each group with the same name, something like `select1[]` and `select2[]`. Then when you post your form back to the server, the selected options will magically be in an array.

If you want to limit the number of selected boxes, then you will have to use some javascript that fires on the click event of each checkbox to count the number selected and allow or disallow any further selections.